# Scatter Plot With Multi Column Data in Plotly Express

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have a `pandas` dataframe like below

```
            x        s       y
Date
2021-06-25  1       red      2
2021-06-28  2       red      3
2021-06-29  3       red      4
2021-06-25  1       blue     2
2021-06-28  2       blue     3
2021-06-29  3       blue     4
```

How can I create a scatter plot in `plotly`[express]/`cufflinks` like [image: scatter plot]

such that plot axes are `x` and `y` and `red` and `blue` are separate traces in the plot.
Any hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- your sample data looks problematic, both red and blue have same values.  Have added .5 to blue to demonstrate
- simple **pandas** to structure data first, so colors are columns
- then use **plotly express** `scatter()`

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Date            x        s       y
2021-06-25  1       red      2
2021-06-28  2       red      3
2021-06-29  3       red      4
2021-06-25  1       blue     2.5
2021-06-28  2       blue     3.5
2021-06-29  3       blue     4.5"""), sep="\s+").set_index("Date")

df2 = df.set_index(["x","s"]).unstack("s").droplevel(0,1)

px.scatter(df2, x=df2.index, y=df2.columns)
```

[image]